# "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" OR "KeyError:" with openpyxl and ipwhois

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, nonetype, whois, keyerror

I'm working on a python3 script that does the following:

1. Open an excel file in the working directory
2. Select the first sheet in the excel file
3. Select all data in the third column (in this case a range of IP addresses)
4. Iterate through all of the IP addresses and call the whois API for each
5. Store results for each IP in variable (.json)
6. Parse through the result looking for Name, IP Range, Contact Info
7. Write the values from 6 above to new rows in the excel file
8. Save the excel file with a new name in the current directory

The current document has a list of 427 unique IP addresses and the results from the whois api for the RIPE name are unique (sometimes within the same response).  To accommodate this, I have iterated through each RIPE name to get secondary data sets within the ['contact'] list. This works fine as long as the contact list contains the values I want.  If it does not, I get an error of NoneType.  I tried to build preventative logic around this with an if statement where result == None to assign my variables with a 'NULL' value, but then I get a KeyError exception on the RIPE name.  I'm stuck and need your help.  Here is a copy of my code:

```
import openpyxl

from pprint import pprint
from ipwhois import IPWhois

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Abuse Log with Notes FWC 2016-06-09.xlsx')#change name here to file to be used 
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1') #get first sheet in workbook

#Add new column headings for API results
sheet['E1'] = 'HOST NAME'
sheet['F1'] = 'HOST COUNTRY'
sheet['G1'] = 'IP START'
sheet['H1'] = 'IP END'
sheet['I1'] = 'HOST EMAIL'
sheet['J1'] = 'HOST PHONE'
sheet['K1'] = 'HOST ADDRESS'

#Store all start range IP's for Amazon in one list variable
AmazonStartIPs = [
  '54.64.0.0', '54.160.0.0','54.144.0.0',
  '52.64.0.0','54.208.0.0','54.192.0.0',
  '54.240.0.0','54.224.0.0','54.72.0.0',
  '54.176.0.0','52.32.0.0','52.0.0.0',
  '52.192.0.0','52.84.0.0','53.32.0.0']

def checkForAmazon():
   if StartAddress in AmazonStartIPs:
      Name = 'Amazon Web Services - Elastic Compute Cloud'
      CountryCode = 'US'
      AbuseEmail = 'abuse@amazonaws.com'
      AbusePhone = '+1-206-266-4064'
      AbuseAddress = ['410 Terry Avenue','North Seattle', 'WA', '98109-5210','UNITED STATES']

iterateColumn = sheet.columns[2]#get all cell values in column C
currentRowIndex = 2

for Address in iterateColumn[1:5]:#test range 1:5 to reduce API load
   ip_address = Address.value#set var to value of item in iterateColumn
      IP = IPWhois(ip_address)#store whois call in var of IP
      results = IP.lookup_rdap(depth=1)#call whois and store .json results

      Name = results['network']['name']#set name to IP Host name
      Name=''.join(Name)#formatting for excel

      CountryCode = results['asn_country_code']#var for country code
      CountryCode=''.join(CountryCode)

      StartAddress = results['network']['start_address']#var for IP range Start
      StartAddress=''.join(StartAddress)

      EndAddress = results['network']['end_address']#var for IP range End
      EndAddress = ''.join(EndAddress)

      #write values above to iterable rows in spreadsheet
      sheet.cell(row = currentRowIndex, column = 5).value = Name
      sheet.cell(row = currentRowIndex, column = 6).value = CountryCode
      sheet.cell(row = currentRowIndex, column = 7).value = StartAddress
      sheet.cell(row = currentRowIndex, column = 8).value = EndAddress

      for key in results['objects']:#get unique key values in results object
         r = key#store as var of r to prevent having to call by ripe name

      AbuseEmail = results['objects'][r]['contact']['email'][0]['value']
      if results['objects'][r]['contact']['email'] == None: 
         AbuseEmail = 'NULL'
      elif results['objects'] is None:
         AbuseEmail = 'NULL'

      sheet.cell(row = currentRowIndex, column = 9).value = AbuseEmail
      AbuseEmail = ''.join(AbuseEmail)

      if results['objects'][r]['contact']['phone'] == None:
         AbusePhone = 'NULL'
      else: 
         AbusePhone = results['objects'][r]['contact']['phone'][0]['value']

      sheet.cell(row=currentRowIndex, column = 10).value = AbusePhone
      AbusePhone = ''.join(AbusePhone)

      if results['objects'][r]['contact']['address'] == None:
         AbuseAddress = 'NULL'
      else:
         AbuseAddress = results['objects'][r]['contact']['address'][0]['value']

      sheet.cell(row=currentRowIndex, column = 11).value = AbuseAddress
      AbuseAddress =''.join(AbuseAddress)

      checkForAmazon()

      currentRowIndex += 1


rowsUpdated = sheet.max_row
print('{} records have been updated.'.format(rowsUpdated))

wb.save('ABUSE_IP_LOG_HOST_DATA.xlsx')
```

Comment: Use a `try`/`except` clause for each case where there may be a key error.

Comment: I added try/except for all cases and that solved the problem.  Thank you MattDMo!

Comment: I'd suggest you separate the code that does the lookup and converts it into a usable form from the code that adds it to the worksheet. The `sheet.cell(…)` as you are using is something I'm keen to discourage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by MattDMo, I added the following exception handling and that resolved the problem:

```
try:
   AbuseEmail = results['objects'][r]['contact']['email'][0]['value']
   AbusePhone = results['objects'][r]['contact']['phone'][0]['value']
   AbuseAddress = results['objects'][r]['contact']['address'][0]['value']
except (KeyError, TypeError):
   AbuseEmail = 'NULL'
   AbusePhone = 'NULL'
   AbuseAddress = 'NULL'
```

Comment: I would rather first assign null. That way you can get even part of data to variables.